# Count number of rows for Cakephp querybuilder

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, query-builder

I am writing a custom function in a Member controller.
The purpose of the function is this:-

1. First it checks if an id exists in the `members` table.
2. If it doesn't exist then it returns 0;
3. if it exists, then it checks whether the isActive status is 0 or 1;
4. if it's 0, then it returns 0, else 1;

Now, I am writing the function as these:-

```
public function memberExist($id)
{
    $query = "SELECT Member.id FROM members AS Member WHERE Member.id = $id AND Member.isActive = 1";
    // Here I want to write something like:
    // if($this->query($query)->num_rows()>0) return 1; else return 0;
}
```

However, the problem is, I don't now how to get number of rows from query builder(sorry if the name is not exact, I am new to cakephp).

`$this->query($query)` returns array.

In controller, we can use following method to get number of rows,

```
$userdata = $this->Member->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('Member.id'=>$id, 'Member.isActive'=>1)));
```

But how to apply count procedure in the Model?

Comment: `$this->Member` is a model object, think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $this->query($query) return arrays,
you can count row by :

```
$records = $this->query($query);
$n = count($records); //count of rows
```

read this for details  http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_array_count.asp

Answer (score 0):

This should work for multiple member ids (where 1, 2, 3 ... is your member ids):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(Member.id) as count FROM members AS Member WHERE Member.id in (1, 2, 3, 4) AND Member.isActive = 1;";
```

for single member id:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(Member.id) as count FROM members AS Member WHERE Member.id = ".$id." AND Member.isActive = 1;";
```

Number of rows will represented by `$your_result_var['count']`;